# How am I going to convert an id with a date and timestamp into an ObjectId using kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, mongodb-query, objectid

```json
"id": {
  "date": "Wed Aug 16 18:51:43 PST 2023",
  "timestamp": 1692183103
}
```

I need to convert this id into an ObjectId, "64dcaa3fcac7f22c65bf21e8".

Here is my code:

```kotlin
val inputDate = id.getString("date")
val timestamp = id.getLong("timestamp")

val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)
val date = dateFormat.parse(inputDate)
val time = date.time / 1000L
val timeHex = timestamp.toString(16).padStart(8, '0')

return timeHex.substring(8) + timeHex.substring(0, 2) + timeHex.substring(2, 8)
```

however it is returning only "64dcaa3f"

What should I do?

Comment: You've parsed a date and used it to create a `time` variable, but the `time` variable appears to be unused after being created. Is that a mistake?

Comment: I doubt you can derive an object id from that value, because only the first 4 bytes are the timestamp, the rest are a random value and a counter, see [Quick Start: BSON Data Types - ObjectId](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/mongodb/bson-data-types-objectid/). In other words, you currently have the 4 bytes of the timestamp, but you're missing all the other information you'd need to derive an object id.

Comment: @Sam The conversion done by the OP with `date` is entirely unnecessary, as it is simply the textual representation of `timestamp`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, i see so my approach in passing the id value is not possible. thank you so much for your input

Answer (score -1):

I think this code will work for you.

```
val inputDate = id.getString("date")
val timestamp = id.getLong("timestamp")

val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)
val date = dateFormat.parse(inputDate)
val time = date.time / 1000L
val timeHex = timestamp.toString(16).padStart(8, '0')

val objectId = timeHex.substring(0, 4) + timeHex.substring(8) + timeHex.substring(2, 8)

return objectId
```

This code get this output: **64dcaa3fcac7f22c65bf21e8**